# Ubuntu 16.04 on macOS 10.13.6, MacBook Pro 2018 dual boot, not recognizing internal hard drive

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, hard-drive, macbook-pro

I've purchased a MacBook Pro 2018 with High Sierra version 10.13.16, and want to dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 for work purposes. I partitioned my hard drive with 75GB of space, with format MS-DOS (FAT 32).

rEFInd, flashing a USB, and booting to it works fine up until the installation process. The keyboard and mousepad don't work during the process (but I've gotten around that with external peripherals). The issue is that the installation doesn't show the internal MacBook Pro hard drive. It also warns right before looking for internal storage that I may have trouble in the future booting to other OSs if I continue in UEFI mode, since I'm currently running in "BIOS compatibility mode" which looks something like this, but with "Ubuntu" instead of Lubuntu.

[image]

I booted into Ubuntu on my flash drive (trying without installing) and ran GParted. When looking under devices, that also didn't show my Mac's internal hard drive.

Is there any way to make this appear?

Comment: Did you solve this??

Comment: Nope. Waiting for official Ubuntu support. I'm running a VM which works nicely.

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: Nope. Still can’t get it to work.